# Development for changing wifi configuration programmatically in android M? remove saved wifiaswords not working

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

```
    String BACKSLASH = "\"";
    String NETWROK_SECURITY_WEP = "WEP";
    String NETWROK_SECURITY_NONE = "NONE";
    String NETWROK_SECURITY_WPA = "WPA";
    String NETWROK_SECURITY_WPA2 = "WPA2";
    String NETWROK_SECURITY_WPA_WPA2 = "WPA/WPA2 PSK";
    String NETWROK_ADDITIONAL_SECURITY_TKIP = "TKIP"; 
    String NETWROK_ADDITIONAL_SECURITY_AES = "AES";
    String NETWROK_ADDITIONAL_SECURITY_WEP = "WEP";
    String NETWROK_ADDITIONAL_SECURITY_NONE = "NONE";
    int FAILED_TO_ADD_NETWORK = -1;

    WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
    String wifiName = sSid;
    conf.SSID = BACKSLASH + wifiName + BACKSLASH;
    String securityType = NETWROK_SECURITY_WPA_WPA2;

    if (NETWROK_SECURITY_WEP.equalsIgnoreCase(securityType)) {
    conf.wepKeys[0] = pass;
    conf.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
    conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);

    conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
    } else if (NETWROK_SECURITY_NONE.equalsIgnoreCase(securityType)) {
    conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
    } else if (NETWROK_SECURITY_WPA.equalsIgnoreCase(securityType)
    || NETWROK_SECURITY_WPA2.equalsIgnoreCase(securityType)
    || NETWROK_SECURITY_WPA_WPA2.equalsIgnoreCase(securityType)) {
    conf.preSharedKey = BACKSLASH + pass + BACKSLASH;
    conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);


    conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
    conf.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;

    conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);

    conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);

    conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);



   conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);


   conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
   conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
    conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
    }
    String wlanAdditionalSecurity = "";





 if(NETWROK_ADDITIONAL_SECURITY_TKIP.equalsIgnoreCase(wlanAdditionalSecurity)) {

    conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);


   conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
    } else if 
(NETWROK_ADDITIONAL_SECURITY_AES.equalsIgnoreCase(wlanAdditionalSecurity)) {

   conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);

   conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
   } else if 
   (NETWROK_ADDITIONAL_SECURITY_WEP.equalsIgnoreCase(wlanAdditionalSecurity)) {

    conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);

    conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
    } else if (NETWROK_ADDITIONAL_SECURITY_NONE.equalsIgnoreCase(wlanAdditionalSecurity)) {



   conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.NONE);
   }
   WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) 
   mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
   int res = wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
   wifiManager.disconnect();
   wifiManager.reconnect();

   if (true) {
   wifiManager.enableNetwork(res, true);

   wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
   wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

   new AppPreferences(mContext).setPrefrenceLong("connectTime", 
   Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
   }
   if (res != -1) {

   setFalseOther(mm);
   notifyDataSetChanged();

   Intent i = new Intent(mContext, Connect.class);
   i.putExtra("networkName", mm.getName());
   i.putExtra("networkId", mm.getId());
   i.putExtra("AdminID", mm.getUserId());
   i.putExtra("networkConnection", "true");

   mContext.startActivity(i);

        }
```

> This code works in android lollipop but not for marshmallow .unable to
>   remove saved passwords before connecting to next Wifi network in
>   marshmallow

Development for changing wifi configuration programmatically in android M? remove saved wifiaswords not working

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use any of the dangerous permissions according to this doc https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous on android-M. You will need to request permissions at run-time for using them on android-M.Use this link to do so:https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: After allowing all the premission required still facing the same issue !!

Comment: Write run time permission code in your activity file.

Comment: I've already given all the required run time permissions for marshmallow in activity ,this code is just for connection which is not working in marshmallow.